Getting nltk certificate verify failed error with Visual Studio Code with Python3
I got this error. As you can see I have import nltk and nltk.download in my code per their guide.:
[nltk_data] Error loading words: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)>

My Code:
import re # To remove regular expressions. Like ? ! . ,
import tkinter as tk # This is a graphical UI
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText # Widget

import nltk
nltk.download('words') # Check wether a word is valid
from nltk.corpus import words



class SpellingChecker:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk() # tk.Tk refers to a class within the Tkinter module, which is a standard GUI
        self.root.geometry("600x500")

        self.text = ScrolledText(self.root, font=("Helvetica", 14))
        self.text.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.check) # To check words whenever we release a key
        self.text.pack()

        self.old_spaces = 0 # By default we have 0 whitespaces

        self.root.mainloop() # To get the GUI running


    def check(self, event):
        content = self.text.get("1.0", tk.END)  # 1.0 is the first character, 1.1 is the second character, 1.2 is the third character etc.  # tk.END this gives the full content of the text box
        space_count = content.count(" ") # Count the white spaces

        if space_count != self.old_spaces: # If space count is not the same, != as self.old_spaces
            self.old_spaces = space_count

            for tag in self.text.tag_names():
               self.text.tag_delete(tag)
            
            for word in content.split(" "):
                if re.sub(r"[^\w]", "", word.lower()) not in words.words():
                    position = content.find(word)
                    self.text.tag_add(word, f"1.{position}", f"1.{position + len(word)}")
                    self.text.tag_config(word, foreground="red")
        
SpellingChecker()


I'm on MacOS and I got Python3 installed.
Searching for answers.
I tried to re add them, say nltk3, check forums, yt videos. nothing.

Used a VPN and then added some certificate code at the top.
